# Can I change block size or put seats in small ships?

Tags: space-engineers

I'm working on a ship build, but have run into a small problem. If I want fine detail for the exterior, I have to use small blocks instead of large blocky ones.
But then if I choose to use a small ship **for** the small blocks, I'm stuck with a cockpit instead of a Control Station or Flight Seat, which I want one, so I can hop out and walk around my ship instead of abruptedly been ejected out.

Is there a way I can resize **Large Ship** blocks or put a controllable seat **inside** a **Small Ship**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Blocks

You can't use the **small blocks** on the **large ship** designs. You can use mods from the steam workshop to add this functionality as far as I know. But it's not possible in vanilla.

## Cockpits/Seats

As for seats, it's also as simple as no. You can't put seats in **small ships**, but can put Cockpits in **large ships**.

Comment: Can you please provide me with some more information such as a link for the workshop please? And also, how about the cockpit/seats? I'm more worried about them than the blocks...

Comment: I haven't checked if there is one available at the moment that adds in what you want specifically. But you can't use a control panel for a small ship in vanilla. I don't know who downvoted my answer but this is what it's like in vanilla. You get diff sized blocks and functional blocks depending if it's a small or big ship. Can't mix them.

Comment: Well... Sadly it's a nono then. I can't seem to find one, but get back to me if you find anything workshop wise. xD Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is wrong. You can connect small ships to large ships using rotors.

Comment: @Philipp But in what way can you place control panels on small ships or place large block on small blocks. You are giving an alternative entirely instead of answering the question. Doesn't make the answer wrong which by the way was completed by Finn with his findings. What Finn was aiming for here was the equivalent of this mod for minecraft. http://www.minecraftmods.com/littleblocks-mod/ Allowing smaller sized blocks to be placed on larger ones for either detail or functionality.

Comment: @TomKriek So how is your answer correct? You say "there surely is a mod for it", but turns out there is not. You say "it's not possible in vanilla", but it is possible in vanilla using rotors.

Comment: @Philipp I'm inclined to say read the question and answer out loud. You are straw-manning my arguments and comments. I said the functionality could be added with a mod. E.g. like they did with minecraft. Besides that I answered to the other question in the comments and Finn added that to the answer that was already there. There is a big difference between using small blocks on big blocks and connecting two ships with rotors. Good alternative but maybe enforce it like that and not as a definite answer.

Comment: @Philipp So theres no way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

To transfer from small to large blocks and vice versa use **Rotors**.

1. build the large ship/station and the small ship separately
2. Build a large rotor on a large ship/station
3. Deconstruct the top part with your grinder
4. Add a "Rotor *Part*" (only the top section of a rotor) to the small ship. Have the stick-part face outwards
5. Maneuver the rotor part of the small ship into the rotor of the large ship
6. Switch to the control panel of the large ship, select the rotor and click "attach"

The two ships have now merged into one for most purposes. The large blocks can have other large blocks added to them and the small blocks can have small blocks added. There is, however, a limitation: You can only control the gyroscopes and engines of the rotor-section you are currently sitting in, so you can not use this to have a control station control a small ship or a fighter cockpit control a large ship.

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gw8Qo0ThNos) shows how this works.

A word of warning though: A rotor which still has the maximum torque setting can create a jolt of enormous force the moment it attaches to a new rotor part. This can damage the ship you build and/or the surrounding. So it is recommended to reduce the torque to a minimum and put it back (for stability) after the small ship is attached correctly.